# SOQL query with inner query doesn't recognize understand the relationship

Tags: apex, soql, relationships, childrelationship

I'm trying to write a SOQL query that will retrieve a list of Content sObjects and return it's related child Attribute sObjects.

First I wrote the SOQL query to grab the parent records, and it returns the expected results:

```
SELECT cms__Name__c, cms__Published_Start_Date__c FROM cms__Content__c WHERE cms__Published_Start_Date__c <= 2017-03-22T18:14:26.128Z AND cms__Content_Type__r.Name = 'CT-000068' LIMIT 10
```

The problem comes when I try to add the inner query to select the Attribute records.  The following is the same query with the addition of the inner query:

```
SELECT cms__Name__c, cms__Published_Start_Date__c, (SELECT cms__Name__c, cms__Value__c, cms__Type__c, cms__Language__c from cms__Attribute__r) FROM cms__Content__c WHERE cms__Published_Start_Date__c <= 2017-03-22T18:14:26.128Z AND cms__Content_Type__r.Name = 'CT-000068' LIMIT 10
```

You'll notice I am querying on the relationship in the inner query, denoted by use of cms__Attribute__r.  I've confirmed in workbench this is in fact the name of the relationship:

[image: relationship name=cms__Attribute__r]

So what's going on here?  I would expect that this would return me a List of Content records, each record with their child list of Attribute records.

Thinking maybe developer console just wasn't smart enough to visually display a 1:M relationship, I tried to run the query in my APEX code as well, but no luck.

Here's the full exception I've received:

> cms__Type__c, cms__Language__c from cms__Attribute__r) FROM cms__Content__c
>                                       ^
>
> ERROR at Row:1:Column:125 Didn't understand relationship
>   'cms__Attribute__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting
>   to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the
>   custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe
>   call for the appropriate names.

I believe I did - what else am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed the `s`. Notice the describe says the relationship name is `cms__Attributes__r`, but you have `cms__Attribute__r`.

**Invalid**

```
(SELECT ... FROM cms__Attribute__r)
```

**Valid**

```
(SELECT ... FROM cms__Attributes__r)
```

Comment: Ahhhh of course, thank you!  I can accept this as correct in 9 minutes

Comment: @splatto And the limit has elapsed. Welcome to SFSE!

Comment: Done and done! @Adrian Larson